# People in a rural area hide in warehouse, at end it’s 2 people left, guy leaves her for dead - she lives, then she leaves him to die on road

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, post-apocalyptic, zombie

I saw this movie on Netflix when I was pretty young and the year it came out was maybe around 2012-2017 to be safe but I think mostly 2012-2015.

The main character was a girl with short brown/black hair, she had a simple dress on I think?

The other main guy I don’t remember much just that he was creepy and quiet and tried to SA her and MAYBE he was a doctor?

I don’t remember the other survivors in detail just that they were inside as well and at some point one of them shot someone or a zombie in the face and it freaked everyone out and the body was out there for a while. They weren’t always inside, they were outside sometimes, but went inside for the night.

I can only remember the end where he tries to leave her to die, but she ends up making it. Then she stabs him with something and he just lays on the floor watching her walk away while zombies slowly walk towards him.

Everyone else died so only she survived and it cuts out like that.

The area they were in was very lonely, nothing really surrounded them and it was mostly desert I think, just remember seeing all orange/yellow. The movie was in English. (Not British)

Comment: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1339433/ much too old, but if you like zombies and warehouses, you'll love *Dead End*

Comment: @Valorum thx I’ll check it out :)

Comment: If you've found it, please post it as an answer - it might be useful for someone else in the future!